# More pythonic way to append to two arrays

Tags: python, list

I have a function `foo` that returns two values. Currently, I am iterating through a list as follows:

```
A,B = [],[]
for i in arr:
    a,b = foo(i)
    A.append(a)
    B.append(b)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to accomplish this? I thought the following was sort of ugly, but maybe it's the best way?

```
A,B = np.array([foo(i) for i in arr]).T
```

Comment: Do you define `pythonic` as `one-line-ish`?

Comment: Your first code shows ``list``s, your second code shows ``numpy.array``s. Which do you need?

Comment: I would not introduce numpy just for something trivial like this.

Answer (score -1):

This is a transpose, for which a classic Python pattern exists:

```
a, b = zip(*(foo(i) for i in arr))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is beautiful python.